# JQuery - $.each within $.each wait for function to finish

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, each

I've got an `$.each` loop, that is within another `$.each` that is calling a function to add values to my back end system.

My `$.each` loops are like this:

```
$.each(locations, function( i, location ) { 
    $.each(location, function( i, site ) {
        addsite ( site.url, site.address, site.zip, site.contact, site.id )
    })
})
```

When I call the function `addsites` directly, not from within the `$.each` loops it works as expected, however when called from within the `$.each` loops it works, but sometimes code is being called before other code has completed.

After lots of testing I've worked out it's due to `$.ajax` being called which obviously doesn't complete before the other code is run.

My working function is :

```
function addsite( url, address, zip, contact, id ) {
                
    // 1. lots of jquery
    // 2. lots of jquery
    
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",   
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        complete : function(text) {
            console.log ( '3.' + text )

        }
    });
    
    // 4. more jquery
})
```

I added debugging into points 1, 2, 3 and 4 and could see that everything in 1. and 2. is called correctly, but the code in 4. is being running before the `$.ajax` has completed.

When the function is called in the `$.each` loop, I see 1,2,4 multiple times in the console.log followed by multiple 3's as that is completing later. This needs to be running as 1,2,3,4.

I understand why that happens and have found adding `async: false` to `$.ajax` allows this to work, but that is depreciated so I'm trying to find a better way.

Do I need to do something to the `$.each` loops or the `addsite` function ? If it's the function I need to make sure this works when called directly not just from the `$.each` loops.

Could some advise how I can get this to work correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Why not change the function to accept adding multiple sites at a time? Doing this you'll do a single request instead of multiple ones.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking here. Is this about the second part of `addsite` running before the Ajax call in part one has resolved? Or is it about the `each` loop?

Comment: My issue is in the addsite function and the code being run before `$.ajax` is completed. I'll add some additional comments to the original post.

Comment: Move the `2` code inside `complete` or `await $.ajax`.

Comment: I tried moving 2 but that didn't help

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry that I didn't immediately see that it can't be used `async: false` in ajax request.

Now reworked the cycles on `for of` and add `async await`, made a test case:

```js
//  for example, the location is only with id
const locations = [
  [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2}
  ],
  [
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4}
  ]
];

//  your function
const addsite = async( url, address, zip, contact, id ) => {

  console.log(`before ${id}`); //  before ajax scripts
  
  await $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',   
    url: 'https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity', //  for testing
    cache: false,
    complete : function(text) {
      console.log(`${id} is complete`); //  site added
    }
  });
  
  console.log(`after ${id}`); //  after ajax scripts
  console.log(''); //  just divider
  
};

//  loops
(async () => {
  for (let location of locations) { //  first loop
    for (let site of location) { //  second loop
      await addsite(site.url, site.address, site.zip, site.contact, site.id);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using `async:false`

Comment: The question explicitly says "have found adding async: false to $.ajax allows this to work, but that is depreciated so I'm trying to find a better way".

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't immediately see that it can't be used `async: false`. Corrected the answer.

Comment: Please check if everything is working properly now?